# Datagrid cell's Numeric Validation in c#

Tags: c#

i want to validate a separate cells in datagrid. if i want only numbers in a particular cell in the datagrid how can i do it.

for example :

im using Datagrid View.
there the datagrid with 3 columns. ID,Name,Phone number
i want to validate this phone number field. if user enter a some other values than a number i want to give a error message.

this may be a easy task as im very new to c# please someone help me with this problem.

thank you all

Answer (score 1):

do you have a public bool validatePhone(string PhoneNumber) method ?
if so drag an errorProvider control to your form.
If so you can call that method in the text_changed event of the phone number field. something like this -

phoneNumber = phoneNumberTextBox.Text;

if (validatePhone(phoneNumber)==false)
      {
          errorProvider.SetError(phoneNumberTextBox," Please enter a valid phone number");
      }
    if (validatePhone(phoneNumber) == true)
     {
        errorProvider.SetError(phoneNumberTextBox,"");
     }

you can also call it on the Validating event, I belive this waits unti the user leaves the field, probabbly a better way if it is a web app. For a desktop, use the text_changed event.

If all the form fields relate to one object, you can also add the errors via databinding, but I do not have enough exp to explian this. I did implement it, but the object and validation had been written for me , I just hooked it up to the form. It work really nicley, dragged an errorProveider and databinding to my form, then set the datasource of each and of each field to the object. The error info was automatic with one line of code in the Form_Load event :

```
  bindingObject.DataSource = insatantiatedObject;
```

Comment: It may also be handy to catch the OnKeyPress event (for WinForms) and allow only numbers and other characters specific to a phone number.